# Using chain rule to calculate $DF(0,0,0)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} ,g:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ funtions of clase $C^{\infty}$ such that $f(0,0,0)=g(0,0)=h(0),Df(0,0,0)=(1,2,3),Dg(0,0)=(4,5)$ and $h'(0)=6$.If $$F(x,y,z)=f(g(x,y),h(z),f(x,h(x),g(x,x))),$$calculate $DF(0,0,0)$.

I tried use the chain rule butI got confused, I tried to let $u=g(x,y), v=h(z), w= f(x,h(x),g(x,x))$ but I don't think it's the right thing to do.

Comment: I think you have got a couple of typos? (i) is it $f(0,0,0)=g(0,0)=h(0)=0$? (ii) is it $h'(0)=6$?  I think you just have to use the Chain Rule twice and hold tight and it will come out.

Comment: For i) it is, and for ii) you're right, is $h'(0)=6$

Comment: So, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}  + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} $?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Is right $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial h} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, but because $Df(0,0,0)=(1,2,3), g(0,0)=(0,0)$, so $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} =0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =1$, that we have,. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 6\frac{\partial f}{\partial h} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial f} $?

Answer (score 2):

*You need to amend the question as I suggested in the comments and put in the fact that $f(0,0,0)=g(0,0)=h(0)=0$, otherwise  there is not enough information to solve this problem.*

To avoid all sorts of confusion caused by the double occurrence of $f$ let us write $F_i$, $f_i$, $g_i$, $h_i$ on for the derivative of $F$, $f$, $g$ , and $h$ with respect to their $i$-th variable.

The by the Chain Rule (several times) we have
$$
F_1=
f_1 \cdot (g_1 \cdot 1 +g_2 \cdot 0)
+f_2\cdot  0
+f_3 \cdot \left(f_1 \cdot 1+ f_2 \cdot h_1 +f_3 \cdot (g_1\cdot 1 +g_2\cdot 1)\right)
$$
which evaluates at $(0,0,0)$ to
$$
F_1(0,0,0)=
1\cdot (4 +0)
+2\cdot 0
+3 \cdot (1\cdot 1+ 2 \cdot 6 +3 \cdot (4 +5))=124.
$$

The other two components are easy as the $y$ and $z$ occur only once in the definition of $F$.

Comment: I dind't edit  because the original exam don't have that part,  I suppose that they did a mistake